# vs2003: quick snippet tool

Tags: visual-studio-2003

I am working on a HUGE vs2003 website. Is there a quick snippet tool that i could use to connect to my dev database and test out different pieces of my code instead of running website over and over again??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just because you're building a web site doesn't mean that all your code has to be in a web site project. You can create a class library which your web site depends on, and then maybe a console app to make calls to that class library for test purposes.

Ideally, however, you'd have unit tests instead of ad hoc testing. You could create those unit tests with [NUnit](http://nunit.org) or various other test frameworks. (Using .NET 1.1 will limit which versions of those test frameworks you can use, admittedly.)